# Greater than statement with unwanted char in

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table (products) with products and price, like the following:

```
|id|product|price
|1|bicycle|199.00
|2|car|2999.00
|3|doll|19.00
```

I want to be able to get all products with a price greater than X. Although I the below code doesn't work (it gets product that isn't between the intervals) and I think I encounter it because the dot in the price

Im using CodeIgniter and my query looks like this:

```
$this->db->from('products');
$this->db->where('id', $row->product_id);

// If price interval is set
if(!empty($start_price))
{
    $this->db->where('products.price >=', $start_price);
    $this->db->where('products.price <=', $end_price);
}

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Regular statement would be something like

```
$price = 150.00
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE price > ' . $price . '";
```

How can I have a dot in my table column and still use greater than? Its a lot of lines, so changing all is not possible Im afraid

Comment: you want the query to select only start price or both

Comment: Preferably both start and end price. But if I get a solution for greater than I think I will be able to implement it for less than.

Comment: what is the field type in the db? varchar? float? decimal?

Comment: The field is varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your column **price** is declared as e.g. **FLOAT**, **DOUBLE** or **DECIMAL** , this should work

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE price > $start_price1 and price <  $end_price2 ;
```

if it is declared as **VARCHAR**

```
SELECT * FROM products   
 WHERE CAST(price AS FLOAT)> $start_price1  
 AND CAST(price AS FLOAT) < $end_price2;
```

Comment: Perfect, just changed the column to decimal and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This query should work if you have both the limits-

```
$query = "select * from products where price between $p1 and $p2"
```